# Browser says, it can't find the web page

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, browser

If I google something and open all 10 results in new tab, 1 or 2 tabs didn't get loaded and the browser says it can't find the webpage but when i refresh, it loads perfectly.

**I feel that whenever the redirects happen from one site to another, this issue happens. For example, googling(search & open the Google results) and payment site redirects(from bank website to vendor website).**

My main concern is, I've lost money when the bank website can't redirect to the vendor website as they say the payment is pending but actually debited from my account.

Please help me to fix and if possible to understand the issue. If this is not the right place to ask this question, let me know where to post.

Additional info:

- Using Win 7 64 bit professional edition
- Google Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m
- ISP - Airtel
- Using laptop and connected to wireless modem

Comment: Is this happening with a website that you're programming? If not, it doesn't seem like a programming problem we can help you fix.

Comment: superuser.com is a better place to post problems with using your computer, not related to programming.

Comment: its not happening for my site, happens for all sites randomly. thanks for your suggestion to post in superuser.com. posted [link](http://superuser.com/questions/782757/browser-says-it-cant-find-the-web-page)